# MySQL delete first row when new is added when at 15 rows

Tags: php, mysql

When there are `15` rows in a table and then i add a new row, is there a way to automatically delete the first row in that table?

so it should be like this:
ids `1-15` , then when i add a new one: ids `2-16` ,then again i add a new one: ids `3-17` and so on.

edit1:
i now have this code but it doesn't work for me.

```
    $this->db->select('count(*)');
    $this->db->from('chat');

    $countChat = $this->db->get();

    if ($countChat >= '16') {
        $this->db->delete();
        $this->db->from('chat');
        $this->db->order_by('id');
        $this->db->limit('1');
    }
```

Comment: after adding, you could run a query to count the number of rows. If its 15, then delete the first one. Though i also recommend that you add a created date column so you know which row was added first etc

Comment: Maybe use an `INSERT` trigger?  You'll also want to carefully define what "first" means.  Lowest ID?  Something else?  Though honestly I can't imagine why you'd even need something like this, and I highly suspect a poor design decision somewhere outside of this question.

Comment: I need it for a chatbox, i want it to have a max of 15 messages in the chatbox then delete the latest message when a new message is sent, and the first is the lowest id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea to is to include the constraint within the INSERT itself.

Another idea is to only allow UPDATEs, as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY,string VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES 
('2018-01-07 13:04:40 | one'),
('2018-01-07 13:04:45 | two'),
('2018-01-07 13:04:51 | three'),
('2018-01-07 13:04:57 | four'),
('2018-01-07 13:05:02 | five'),
('2018-01-07 13:05:07 | six'),
('2018-01-07 13:05:12 | seven'),
('2018-01-07 13:05:17 | eight'),
('2018-01-07 13:05:22 | nine'),
('2018-01-07 13:05:27 | ten'),
('2018-01-07 13:05:32 | eleven'),
('2018-01-07 13:05:38 | twelve'),
('2018-01-07 13:05:43 | thirteen'),
('2018-01-07 13:05:50 | fourteen'),
('2018-01-07 13:05:54 | fifteen');

UPDATE my_table SET ts = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, string = 'sixteen' ORDER BY ts LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---------------------+----------+
| ts                  | string   |
+---------------------+----------+
| 2018-01-07 13:04:45 | two      |
| 2018-01-07 13:04:51 | three    |
| 2018-01-07 13:04:57 | four     |
| 2018-01-07 13:05:02 | five     |
| 2018-01-07 13:05:07 | six      |
| 2018-01-07 13:05:12 | seven    |
| 2018-01-07 13:05:17 | eight    |
| 2018-01-07 13:05:22 | nine     |
| 2018-01-07 13:05:27 | ten      |
| 2018-01-07 13:05:32 | eleven   |
| 2018-01-07 13:05:38 | twelve   |
| 2018-01-07 13:05:43 | thirteen |
| 2018-01-07 13:05:50 | fourteen |
| 2018-01-07 13:05:54 | fifteen  |
| 2018-01-07 13:07:15 | sixteen  |
+---------------------+----------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 2):

when you add new row in table then you should delete minimum id like this

```
DELETE FROM myTable 
ORDER BY my_id
LIMIT 1;
```

make sure your `id` is `auto-increment`.

As per your requirement first you count total rows

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename;
```

then used `if` condition

```
if($countRows >= 15)
{
   // execute delete query
}
```

Comment: This looks like what i'm looking for, but is there a way to also make it check if the table has 15 rows before it deletes the lowest id?

Comment: yes, you can check using `count` like this `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename;`

Comment: i just tried this but it doesn't work for me, i edited my post with the code i have now.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to keep 15 rows in the table in total, then:

```
delete
from yourtable
where yourid < (select yourid
                from yourtable
                order by yourid desc
                limit 14, 1)
```