# Limit the Insert of Records in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

**Limit the Insert of Records in Laravel**

current what i want to achieve is i want to limit the records to suppose a 100 now when ever we try to  insert a new record we should delete the one (first) record and insert the newly created one

currently iam doing  manually like this

```
if(Logs::count() >= 100){ Logs::fist()->delete(); //fuction call again } 
else{ Logs::create(); }
```

i want to simply this and trying to make in centralised

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137006/mysql-delete-first-row-when-new-is-added-when-at-15-rows

Comment: Have you tried Mode observer ?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @apokryfos iam  using mysql

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai do you mean model observer yeah i did find the soltion with it thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get all the records from DB you just need the count of records

```
/**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();


        static::created(function ($model) {
            /* Getting the log limt */
            $setting = Setting::where(['option' => 'log_queue_size'])->first();
            if ($setting) {
                $limit = $setting->value['log_queue_size'] ?? 100;               
                $actualCount = Log::query()->count();

                if ($actualCount > $limit) {
                    $recordsToDelete = $actualCount - $limit;
                    Log::query()->latest()->take($recordsToDelete)->delete();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: the above solution helps

Answer (score 1):

yes i after some researh i find solution i have used model observer

```
protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function ($model) {
           /* Getting the log limt */
            $setting = Setting::where(['option' => 'log_queue_size'])->first();
            if ($setting) {
                $limit = $setting->value['log_queue_size'] ?? 100;
                $logQuery = Log::get();

                $keepIds = $logQuery->take($limit)->pluck('id');
                Log::whereNotIn('id', $keepIds)->delete();
            }
           
        });
    }
```